# Getting the mean of two rows in data frame based on the condition of one column

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, apply, mean

I have the following sample data frame:

```
df<-data.frame(A=c(rep(1:4,4)),B=runif(16,min=0,max=16),c=rnorm(16, mean=6,sd=2))
```

I want to collapse the data frame by creating a new value for column A as the average of two existing values. For instance, create a new data frame with values of `A` as `1,2.5,4` instead of `1:4`. In doing so, the rows of the df containing `2` and `3` will be removed and the new df will contain only `12` rows instead of `16`.

EDIT

Desired output is some thing like this.

```
   A          B        c
1  1    8.248871 4.402726
2  2.5  11.694196 4.2878085
4  4    8.036312 2.014886
5  1    9.828333 3.240945
6  2.5  1.151633 2.918831
8  4    12.176981 4.874183
9  1    14.067821 5.480923
10 2.5  6.145208 6.139448
12 4    6.352356 2.586025
13 1    3.423057 5.114978
14 2.5  11.005555 3.265489
16 4    14.579750 3.783269
```

Comment: What will happen to the rows of `B` and `C`?

Comment: @akash87 B and C will be averaged on the condition of A.

Comment: Can you state your desired output?

Comment: How did you compute e.g. `df[2, B]` which is `11.694196`? Its unclear to me.

Comment: @m0h3n. I used calculator and just sorted it in data frame. I didn't really calculate the actual value for others.\

Answer (score 2):

I would write a collapse function:

```
collapse_df <- function(mydf, column, omit, pair, FUN) {
  ind <- which(mydf[,column] %in% pair[1])
  ind2 <- mydf[,column] %in% pair[-1]
  m <- mapply(function(x,y) lapply(mydf[x:y,!names(mydf) %in% omit], FUN), ind, ind+1L)
  mydf[ind,] <- cbind.data.frame(mydf[ind,omit], t(m))
  mydf[!ind2,]
}

collapse_df(df, "A", pair=2:3, FUN=mean)
#      A         B         c
# 1  1.0  1.060170  4.797753
# 2  2.5  9.577249  6.635214
# 4  4.0  5.612720  3.413631
# 5  1.0  1.734932 10.487560
# 6  2.5  9.577249  6.635214
# 8  4.0  6.529387  5.760596
# 9  1.0  2.517647  5.469165
# 10 2.5  9.577249  6.635214
# 12 4.0  4.243273  6.493916
# 13 1.0 10.118011  4.431953
# 14 2.5  9.577249  6.635214
# 16 4.0  1.563981  5.047428
```

We can also summarise with other functions like the median or sum:

```
collapse_df(df, column="A", pair=2:3, FUN=median)
collapse_df(df, "A", 2:3, sum)
collapse_df(iris[-5], column=1, seq(5,6,.1), median)
```

Comment: Thank you. I have 13 variables  like A B C, how can I proceed with the above solution?

Comment: Are you still checking `2` and `3` in column `A`?

Comment: @ Pierre Lafortune Yes. But my actual values are like `400` and `500` instead of `2`and `3`. I guess that is not a problem.

Comment: No it shouldn't be. Have you tried the function out at all?

Comment: Are you looking for a pairwise average for each set? My function only finds an overall average.

Comment: Yes. I tried your funtion in my actual data set like:`_ collapse_df <- a function(mydf, column, to_collapse, FUN) {
+ ind <- mydf[,column] %in% to_collapse
+ ind2 <- mydf[,column] %in% to_collapse[-1]
+ mydf[ind,] <- lapply(mydf[ind,], FUN)
+ mydf[!ind2,]
+ }
collapse_df(b,"Alt.m",200:300,FUN=mean)`_    I got error message like ` Error in mydf[, column] : incorrect number of dimensions`. what do you think?

Comment: @Pieree Lafortune. Yes, pairwise average.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116008/discussion-between-pierre-lafortune-and-g1124e).

Comment: @ Pierre Lafortune What if I don't want to omit the "Launch.Date"? I tried to modify the function but I was getting error messages constantly.

Comment: Why do you not want to omit it from the summary function? You can't summarise the date with an average. Omit does not mean to leave it out of the output, it just means to leave it out of the mean function.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to keep the date for the average we got. In the solution with the above code it is giving me `NA` for the new averaged row.

Comment: If you would like no columns omitted use `omit=FALSE`